# Дополнить метод базового класса новым функционалом PHP

Tags: php, ооп, полиморфизм, класс

Давно не могу найти ответ на вопрос
сразу код

```
<?php

Class A{

 public function foo(){
  echo "foo";
}
}
Class B extends A  { // или без extends
public function extend_foo(){
  echo "<br>extended_foo";
}
}

$a = new A;
$a->foo()// должно вывести foo<br>extended_foo
?>
```

Фишка в чем если возможность дополнять функционал метода в классе A (используя средства ООП) методом из класса B
вызывать надо именно!! дополненный функционалом метод foo из класса A!!

Comment: **Нет**, потому что базовый класс никакого понятия не имеет о том, какие другие классы его расширяют.

Comment: Чтобы добавить функционала в базовый класс надо либо отредактировать этот класс, либо посмотреть в сторону декораторов.

Comment: можно 1) сделать метод `bar()` который будет вызываться внутрии `foo` и перекрываться в наследниках. 2) можно передавать callback для вызова `foo` 3) как вариацию - сделать некую подписку на события при вызове

Comment: Про пункт 1 - топикстартеру надо метод вызывать с родительского класса.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то, зная имя дочернего класса, самое простое вот так

```php
<?php

Class A {
    public function foo() {
        $child = new B();
        echo "foo".$child->extend_foo();
    }
}

Class B {
    public function extend_foo(){
        echo "<br>extended_foo";
   }
}

$a = new A;
$a->foo();// должно вывести foo<br>extended_foo
?>
```